# Killing a procces with a given name and display the PID

Tags: shell, unix

so here I have an essay and I need to make a command where I kill all process with a given name then when I enter it it will display the pid of the process's with that name and then kill it and I need to use `tr -s` , `cut` ,
for now this is what I did

```
echo " What do you want to kill? "
read pr
ps -fA| grep -c $pr | grep -v grep | kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -e $pr | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(ps -ef |grep $pr |grep -v grep |tr -s ' ' |cut -f2 -d' ')
    do
        kill $i && echo killed $i
    done
```

The `tr -s ' '`  will squeeze repeated spaces into one space which `cut` can use as a field separator.

Its better and easier to use `pgrep`

i.e

```
kill $(pgrep $pr) && echo done || echo not done
```

Here is the man page: [man pgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

Comment: but it doesn't display the pid's of the killed process ! how can I make that happen ?

Comment: @zaki-madridista edited answer to display pids. I missed that in your question because its difficult to read. Please consider editing your question to make it clearer. i.e. Capital letters at the start of sentences, and periods at the end and judicial use of punctuation. Short clear sentences are best for this sort of thing.

Comment: Why use `ps` at all? If you already have the name, just use `pidof name`. You should also check whether `pidof` returns more than 1 PID (it can, just a `ps name | grep...` can). So why not `printf "%s\n" $(pidof bash) | while read -r pid; do...`

Comment: @david-c-rankin You are correct of course, but the constraint of the exercise was to use `tr -s` and `cut` to parse the output of `ps`. In my answer I suggest `pgrep`

Comment: Ahh, I thought those were examples of being limited to POSIX utilities (since he had neither in his original pipeline). No worries.

Comment: As @NiallCosgrove said I must use tr -s and cut , and grep worked fine for me . But I didn't understand the command  cut -f2 -d ' ' and the tr -s ' ' part too